# Chrome extension, custom context menu item not showing

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I know this question has been asked so many times on this site, e.g. [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29704372/1032492). However, Chrome upgrades so fast and it seems those solutions don't work for the latest version anymore. I also checked [**official doc**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus), doesn't seem to work either.

Here are my files:

**manifest.json**

```
{
  "name": "Try Context Menu",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "permissions": [ "tabs", "contextMenus", "http://*/*", "https://*/*" ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [ "background.js" ],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "icon16.png",
    "48": "icon48.png",
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

**background.js**

```
function clickHandler() {
  alert('great');
}

chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "id": "qwertyuiop",
  "title": "Click Me",
  "contexts": ["page", "selection", "image", "link"],
  "onclick" : clickHandler
});

chrome.contextMenus.onClicked.addListener(clickHandler);
```

Comment: What is your actual question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I carefully read several sample extensions' [**source code**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:contextmenus).

Since I set `"persistent"` to `false`, the extension is running with Event Page. Thus my code works by removing `onclick` from the parameter object of `chrome.contextMenus.create`:

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "id": "qwertyuiop",
  "title": "Click Me",
  "contexts": ["page", "selection", "image", "link"]
});
```

Here's a note from the documentation for [**Event Page**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages):

> 7. If you're using the [**context menus**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus) API, pass a string id parameter to [**`contextMenus.create`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create), and use the [**`contextMenus.onClicked`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#event-onClicked) callback instead of an `onclick` parameter to [**`contextMenus.create`**](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create).

What's really strange is, the note is filed under **best practices**, while if I don't do that, the extension **would not even work**. It's a **must-do** actually.